# How can I get the input value of a text field that has been created with airtable in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to make some further adjustments to an address text field. But the problem is that its made with airtable. I want to get the input of that address and use it to get some data from zillow API for the user. How can I do this? I have viewed the source HTML and I only see the airtable script.

Answer (score 0):

This probably went unanswered for being too vague. I'll try to leave some pointers if anyone stumbles upon this in the future.

Are you the host of the WP page? do you have access to the Airtable base in question? Is the "frontend" viewable? [Airtable's API is pretty well-documented](https://airtable.com/api), simple as it may be. Whatever you need, if it's from a shared view, it can be fetched with a curl request.

Other than that,if the base is public, or shared publicly, and particularly if you need this data at a steady rate or in larger quantities, you'd be better off requesting access and collecting the information with a script from the Scripting app. Since ES6, this is as trivial as doing something like

```
let query = await base.getTable
                               (cursor.activeTableId)

                                .selectRecordsAsync()
                      
let payload, selectAll = query.records.map(rec => rec.name), 


selectAll ?

  payload = { records: JSON.stringify(selectAll) }

          :   console.error('something went wrong')

remoteFetchAsync(('your scraping endpoint', payload)=>
       
               //rock'n'roll past this point
```

})